# How do I add/remove a class in a <div> when it already has classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I add/remove a class from a div when it already has one or more classes?

```
<div class="class1 class2" id="id1">some text</div>



$("#id1").toggleClass("class3"); // doesn't work


$("#id1").toggleClass(" class3"); // doesn't work
```

Do I have to parse the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should definitely work. In fact, the [`toggleClass` example](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/toggleClass) *uses* multiple class names!

Comment: straing it does work, I swear I was trying to do the same thing last night and it wasn't working!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried $("#id1").addClass("classname") and $("#id1").removeClass("classname")?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can iterate through the classes.

[Here's a discussion about in on the JQuery google groups.](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/33a01a43d67e5d7c?pli=1)

EDIT: [Found a SO question related to this also.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529737/jquery-multiple-class-actions)